# How to delete an element from an array of objects in php ?

Tags: php, arrays

How to delete an element from an array in php, where the array consists of objects and I don't know index of object that must be deleted?

Comment: Roll a die. Seriously, what **do** you know about the object that must be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the index of your object (by iterating over the array - or binary searching), and then unset the array at that index.

Answer (score 1):

You have to identify in some way your object.

Use a foreach to traverse your array without knowing your key and remove your object if you can match it in some way.

```
foreach($arr as &$val){
    if($val == ...){ //whatever test you need to inditify your obj
        unset($val);
        break;
    }
}
unset($val); // unset it again cause is a reference to your last traversed value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to see if an object is in an array.

```
function inArray($myObject, $array)
{

  foreach($array as $object)
  {
      if($myObject === $$object)
          return true;
  }

  return false;

}
```

You can transform this function how you like. This is basic knowledge.. I would recommend you to readup on some programming principles.